# Internet slows and drops

Tags: networking

When I ping my pc from my other pc it sometimes gets really high ping, and other times it times out, when I check logs this is what it does everytime it does it.
`cat /var/log/syslog | grep -ai 'network'`

```
May 10 14:30:28 xyz-pc NetworkManager[905]: <info>  [1652207428.2215] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 10 14:30:28 xyz-pc dbus-daemon[902]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=905 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 10 14:30:28 xyz-pc systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 10 14:30:28 xyz-pc systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 10 14:30:29 xyz-pc NetworkManager[905]: <info>  [1652207429.3111] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May 10 14:30:29 xyz-pc whoopsie[4110]: [14:30:29] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 10 14:30:29 xyz-pc whoopsie[4110]: [14:30:29] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 10 14:30:29 xyz-pc whoopsie[4110]: [14:30:29] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 10 14:30:39 xyz-pc systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: There can be a lot of different reasons. You provided no information at all to tell anything. Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? What is the hardware? What is the conntction (wired or wireless), etc.

Comment: It's wireless, I'm on Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Wireless network are not reliable. They depend on how many other people are using the same band, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)